# How to install cuDNN5.1 with .deb file on ubuntu 14

Tags: ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-14.04, cudnn

I was trying to install the latest version of cuDNN (5.1) with `.deb` file. Here are the steps that I tried:

1. download the .deb file (not tar files found for the latest version)
   libcudnn5_5.1.10-1+cuda8.0_amd64.deb
2. `sudo dpkg -i libcudnn5_5.1.10-1+cuda8.0_amd64.deb`
3. `sudo apt-get update`
4. `sudo apt-get install cuDNN`

The last step failed. I tried with 'cudnn' but, the error is

> "E: Unable to locate package cuDNN"

I am not sure what is the correct package name for the last installation step.

J.L.

Comment: I have found the library tar file from NVIDIA website. I will use the tar file to install.

Comment: I'm also installing using the deb files, and I'm finding there is surprisingly little documentation about using the deb files. Is there a reason for this? Why do people prefer the tar file?

Answer (score 2):

Try `sudo apt-get install libcudnn5` and it should tell you that libcudnn5 is already the newest version (5.1.10-1+cuda8.0).

Presumeably this means it is already installed with dpkg -i.